# Conflicting output provided by `N[...]`

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

I am trying to evaluate an expression :

```
(-((I (k2 - k1) (-1 + E^(2 I (k2 - k1) \[Pi])))/(-1 + (k2 - 
      k1)^2))) /. {k1 -> 2, k2 -> 7}
```

This gives output as `0.` exactly. Then I tried this :

```
N[ (-((I (k2 - k1) (-1 + E^(2 I (k2 - k1) \[Pi])))/(-1 + (k2 - 
       k1)^2)))] /. {k1 -> 2, k2 -> 7}
```

This gives output as `-2.55135*10^-16 + 0. I`. Then I read up on the documentation of `N[expr,n]` and find that it can evaluate `expr` to `n` precision and try that.

```
N[ (-((I (k2 - k1) (-1 + E^(2 I (k2 - k1) \[Pi])))/(-1 + (k2 - 
       k1)^2))), 2] /. {k1 -> 2, k2 -> 7}
```

This gives output as `0.*10^-1 + 0.*10^-2 I`. Now, I try this for different values of precision `n` and conclude that the output is zero upto the accuracy provided by precision.

But why does the usage of `N[..]` without any precision give me non zero result? It is of the order of `10^-16` so I thought that maybe `MachinePrecision` is set to `16` but no, trying `N[...,16]` results in exactly zero again.

Can someone please shed light on this so that I can trust the output given by `N[]` ?

Comment: It's roundoff error. Either use `Chop[]` on a machine precision evaluation (`Chop[N[expr]]`) or use arbitrary precision exclusively (`N[expr, prec]`).

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties So, in short, we should never use `N[ ]` without specifying precision even though `Mathematica` doesn't show any errors?

Comment: "Never" is too strong a word. By default, if the second argument of `N[]` is unspecified, it is set to `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)